# How to connect with Django and external mysqlDB

Tags: django

I have 2VM. One is the "Apache+Django" server and one Mysql server. 
I want to know that How connect the Django and externel mysql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change below setting in your settings.py file

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'mydb',    # remote db name                  
        'USER': 'root',    # remote db user                  
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass', #remote db pass                 
        'HOST': 'remote.ip.address.something',#remote ip or url                      
        'PORT': '3306',    # remote post                  
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to make sure that the remote mysql is actually listening on the network interface (by default it only listens on localhost).

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.